# storing text in different rows of MySQL database based on newline

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, textarea

The HTML code is below:

```
<div class="form-data">
    <form method="POST" action="test_upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      ID:<br>
      <input type="text" name="id"><br>                    
      Quote:<br>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="text-file"></textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>        
</div>
```

The corresponding php code is below:

```
<?php

//connect database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","androidtest"); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $quote_id   = $_POST['id'];
    $text        = $_POST['text-file'];         

    //insert data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (quote_id, quote) VALUES ('$quote_id', '$text')";

    //store in the table
    $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);              

    if ($insert) {                      
      echo "Success.";
    } else {
      echo "Error.";
    }

    //close mysql connection
    mysql_close($conn);

    //won't resubmit the form
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);       
}
```

?>

I want to post multiple sentences separated by break in textarea. They should be stored in different rows in MySQL database.
For eg, if i put an id of 2 and post a text having multiple sentences separated by break or newline, then it should store in the database like this:

quote_id   quote 
2            line 1
2            line 2
2            line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code, it may help you. I am not sure the textarea next line seperated by '\n'. Please make sure that

```
//connect database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","androidtest");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $quote_id   = $_POST['id'];
    $get_file   = $_POST['text-file'];
    $textArray = explode("\n", $get_file);
    foreach($textArray as $key=>$value) {
        //insert data
        $sql = "INSERT INTO quotes (quote_id, quote) VALUES ('$quote_id', '$value')";
        //store in the table
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($insert) {
            echo "Success.";
        } else {
            echo "Error.";
        }
    }
    //close mysql connection
    mysql_close($conn);
    //won't resubmit the form
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Now it coming in different rows in MySQL database when I give \n after line 1 and line 2 in the textarea. But all the lines are stored in  the database. I want line 1 in row 1, line 2 in row 2, etc.

Comment: can you see the last table in my question? Now under quote column, line1line2line3 are coming, instead of only line 1.

Comment: I think, your string is not exploding properly. Please check your $textArray variable and confirm it exploding properly and contains 3 array elements